# @NonNullByDefault project-wide setting

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

The [documentation for the @NonNullByDefault attribute](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/annotation/NonNullByDefault.html) states the following:

"If a @NonNullByDefault annotation is used within the scope of another @NonNullByDefault annotation or a project-wide default setting, the innermost annotation defines the default applicable at any given position"

How do I set a project-wide default setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set a project wide default, the javadoc is incorrect and I opened a bug for it - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385540

You can apply a default to a package via package-info.java file